# Am I using correctly Options directive on Apache?

Tags: 14.04, server, permissions, apache2

I am trying not to list any file when I try to access to the root directory by the browser and there isn't any main page associated.

What I do it is to go to the file `apache2.conf` on the directory `/etc/apache2` and modify this line:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
```

to this:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Then I go to the directory `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` and go to the file `dir.conf` in which I comment the following line:

```
#DirectoryIndex mainpage.html index.html ...
```

After that, I restart Apache:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

and when I try to go on my browser to the url `localhost:81` (I am listening on the port 81) a page with the following message appears:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

So here I have some **questions**:

- Why I have to remove `FollowSymLinks` when I use `-Indexes`? If I do not do that an error appears when I try to restart Apache.
- Is it normal that a `Forbidden` message appear? I think that it should show an empty root directory instead of a Forbidden message.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Why I have to remove `FollowSymLinks` when I use `-Indexes`? If I do not do that an error appears when I try to restart Apache.**

Take a look at the error I get when I do this:

```
* The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 165 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Either all Options must start with + or -, or no Option may.
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Apache is simply complaining that each Options line may only have `+` options or `-` options, *not both*.

If you want to use both, you have to split them across two lines, like this:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
```

As to why this is, it's just probably easier to parse each line by itself. It's just how it's designed.

---

> **Is it normal that a `Forbidden` message appear? I think that it should show an empty root directory instead of a Forbidden message.**

It's important to note that `+Indexes` only takes effect if there's no `DirectoryIndex` declaration. During this time, it'll display a list of files (sorta like [this](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/)) as opposed to your `index.html` or whatever. By using `-Indexes`, you're telling Apache to display a Forbidden error if no `DirectoryIndex` is found (or, it's not set and no `index.html` is found).

Comment: So the Forbidden error it is normal when you put `-Indexes`, right?

Comment: @Error404 If there is no `DirectoryIndex`, yes.

Comment: Yes of course I was refearing if there is not any DirectoryIndex. Thank you man. You make me see it more clear :)